# Trying to run single flavor of React Native app on real Android device

Tags: android, react-native

I'm primarily an iOS developer but have inherited a white-labelled React Native app and am having difficulty getting it to run and debug directly on an Android device.  The app was created with RN 0.69.4 and I'm using VSCode.

The various white-labelled apps are able to build and run on iOS (both simulator and device), and on the Android emulator, as well as successfully uploading to TestFlight and Google Play Store Internal, so the core app and configuration is good.  When trying to run the app on a real device Gradle attempts to build all flavors one after the other.

There's a primary version of the white-labelling that I'll use below for example; let's call it `MyApp`.  I'd hope any solution works equally for any other white-labelled version.

I have two `buildTypes`, `debug` and `release`.  The various apps are configured (on Android) via the `productFlavors` section in the `app/build.gradle` file, e.g.:

```
    ...
    productFlavors {
        myApp {
            applicationId 'com.myApp.app'
            // Provided by Fastlane at deployment time
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(System.env.VERSION_CODE ?: 1)
            versionName "1.0.5"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp.app"
        }

        stagingMyApp {
            applicationId 'com.myApp.app'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(System.env.VERSION_CODE ?: 1)
            versionName "1.0.5"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp.app"
        }
    }
    ...
```

(The above look identical, but for each app I have separate `google-services.json` files in `app/src/<flavor>` directories; probably outside the scope of the question but I can provide more info if it's relevant).

The `package.json` script line for the working Android emulator build is:

```
"workingStaging": "ENVFILE=./config/myApp/.env.qa npx react-native run-android --tasks installStagingMyAppDebug"
```

This builds, packages and deploys *only* the correct app to the emulator.  My understanding is that while emulators are targeted by default, if I want to run on a device I just need to provide an additional `--deviceId=<MY DEVICE ID>` argument (ID from `adb devices`) to the `package.json` line, above.  This, however, causes *all* flavors to build, and *none* to deploy to the real (USB-attached, developer enabled, manual .apk/.aab installs working) device.  I've tried adding the `--deviceId` argument at various positions in the command but this makes no difference - all flavors build, regardless.

Is it possible to do what I want - build and deploy a single flavor to a real device in one command?  Happy to consider environment variables, alternative flags, or a reformulation of the command if my understanding of how to combine flavors, build types/variants and/or environment config is incorrect.  Also, first RN post, so let me know if any additional info would be useful, happy to update the question.  TIA!